# Cannot boot Ubuntu at all, default is windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I have had Ubuntu 18 for many years, and just decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.  When turning the computer on with Ubuntu 18, I was provided with a menu for choosing ubuntu or windows.  As of updating to ubuntu 20, I can still get to that menu, but I have to press F12 to get to it every time.  If I do not press F12, the default is windows.

That was doable, but I now have a new problem.  Regardless of whether I choose Windows or Ubuntu, even if I choose Ubuntu, I get Windows.  I cannot access Ubuntu at all.

Comment: It sounds like you need to change the boot priority in your BIOS.  For that, you will need to consult with the documentation for your computer's motherboard. This is not related to any operating system.  You may also need to choose recovery options for Ubuntu or run `boot-repair` from a live session

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site, not a discussion forum. You are most welcome to write an answer to your own question as soon as you find a solution to the problem. As it stands your answer is not valid. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1298314/edit) and the new information we ask in comments **in your question**. See the [community wiki on boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) for details on how to use it.

Comment: Ubuntu 18? Ubuntu 20?  There are no such releases. Ubuntu uses *yy.mm* format (year.month of release) for all server & desktop releases, the *yy* being used only for IoT and specialist appliance/devices releases than can use *snap* packages only, and can be used in cloud too. Specialist releases are usually used headless, so I'd recommend a desktop release and not a device release (ie. *yy.mm* format release and not *yy* based).  Mention of windows implies desktop release would be chosen, but you mention a specialist format release?  What Ubuntu are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

For the initial problem. Have you tried going into the BIOS settings menu and changing the default boot order? Put Ubuntu on top and Windows as the second option. Ubuntu by default shows you the boot menu and let's you choose.

For the second problem, I recommend checking this out: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows).